# ClassCastException:GenericApplicationContext cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot

It is a spring boot project and it uses XML for creation of bean. Now I am writing test case and while doing the same I am facing the class cast Exception while a creating a particular bean

`````
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

     private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
        }

<bean id="springUtility"
        class="com.endeca.infront.web.spring.SpringUtility" scope="singleton" />````

Above is the bean 

Error : Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
`````

Answer (score 1):

You can directly inject MockMvc and omit some of your configuration because it's the default.

So your test class will look like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

     @Autowired
     private MockMvc mockMvc;

     // Add your tests

}
```

If you need to load configuration @ImportResource is the prefered way. Simply put it on the @SpringBootApplication or a @Configuration class.

```
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Simon but the problem is if I don't use "@ContextConfiguration" , it's not able to load the XML file that I am using for the project for bean creation

Comment: I added an example how to use xml configuration.

Comment: In my Application class, I am using both import resource and configuration and it is working fine but in test class, it's giving me fileNotFoundException